# Proving this tree definition with pigeonhole principle

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, trees

I am studying the following tree definition:

Let $T$ be a finite set and a function: $p: T \mathbin{\backslash} \{r\} \rightarrow T$. Then, $(T,p)$ is a tree if and only if, for all $x \in T, p^k(x) = x$ implies $k=0$.

where $r$ is the root of $T$, $p(x)$ is the father of $x$, and $p^k(x)$ is an ancestor of $x$, with $k \geq 1$.

I have the following proof of  $\leftarrow$ sense of the iff:

We will show that if $T$ is not a tree, then there is an integer $k>0$ such as $p^k(y) = y$ for a $y \in T$.

There exists a $x \in T \mathbin{\backslash} \{r\}$ such as $p^k(x) \in T\mathbin{\backslash}  \{r\}$ for all $k \in \{0,1,..., |T|-1 \}$. Since $|I| > |T \mathbin{\backslash}  \{r\} |$, by the pigeonhole principle, there exists $i,j \in I, i < j$, such as $p^i(x) = p^j(x)$. Then, $p^k(y) = y$ with $y = p^i(x)$ and $k=j-i$.

Can someone explain to me why $p^k(p^i(x)) = p^i(x)$ with $k=j-i$ ?

Comment: I don't get it. What's $p(x)$ if $T$ is not a tree?

Comment: I don't get it either. This is how appears in my book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > We will show that if T is not a tree, then there is an integer $k>0$ such as $p^{k}(y)=y$ for a $y \in T$.

This doesn't agree with your definition. You want to show that there is no periodic point. By definition, a tree is acyclic. So it suffices to show that $p$ will end up traversing a cycle. That's how you should go about contrapositive.

You also never define your set $I$.

So we know that $p^{i}(x) = p^{j}(x)$. So $p^{i}(x)$ says to iterate on $p$ $i$ times (compose $p$ with itself $i$ times). The $p^{k}$ term says let's compose $p$ a few more times with itself $(j-i$ more times to be exact) such that we have $p^{j}(x)$. You're really just counting function compositions.

Comment: Thank you, it's more clear now. Do you have any thoughts on $I$? Why it was chosen or defined like that?

Comment: $I$ wasn't ever chosen or defined. That is a problem with the proof. You (or whoever wrote the proof) should have defined $I$ somewhere. I would guess $I = \{1, ..., |V(T)|\}$, which would give you $|I| > |T - \{r\}|$.